# Get longest element in Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I store data in dictionary, where key is an integer, and value is a tuple of integers.
I need to get the length of the longest element, and its key.

I found this for getting the max value over dict:

```
def GetMaxFlow(flows):        
    maks=max(flows, key=flows.get)
    return flows[maks],maks
```

I tried to modify and as a key use the `len` function, but it didn't work, so I tried something reasonable and straightforward, yet inefficient:

```
def GetMaxFlow(flows):
    Lens={}
    for a in flows.iteritems():
        Lens[a[0]]=len(a[1])
    maks=max(Lens, key=Lens.get)
    return Lens[maks],maks
```

Is there a more elegant, and pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is one of the reasons `lambda` still exists in Python I think.

```
def GetMaxFlow(flows):        
    maks=max(flows, key=lambda k: len(flows[k]))
    return flows[maks],maks
```

To specifically return a len...

```
def GetMaxFlow(flows):        
    maks=max(flows, key=lambda k: len(flows[k]))
    return len(flows[maks]), maks
```

Or use [eumiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281968/577088)'s solution, which actually makes more sense in this case. (I misunderstood your question.)

Comment: you could easily just do `def sorting_key(k):return len(flows[k])` then use `sorting_key` in place of the `lambda` so I'm not sure about the argument "still exists in Python" but the argument that definitely works is "this is a case that makes a lot of sense for a `lambda` expression"

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Quite right -- I was thinking about history rather than design -- i.e. "This is one of the reasons there was such resistance to GvR's [plan to remove](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) `lambda` from the language."

Answer (score 8):

If you need the length and the key:

```
def GetMaxFlox(flows):
    return max((len(v), k) for k,v in flows.iteritems())
```

If you need the value and the key:

```
def GetMaxFlox(flows):
    return max((len(v), v, k) for k, v in flows.iteritems())[1:]
```

or

```
def GetMaxFlox(flows):
    return max(((v, k) for k, v in flows.iteritems()), key=lambda (v,k): len(v))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to return a key and a value, not a len and a value.

Comment: " I need to get length of longest element, and its key."

Comment: @senderle - ok, there were two things in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the lengths of all of the elements, you only need to store the key and the length of the currently longest tuple:

```
def GetMaxFlow(flows):
    maks_length=0
    for key,value in flows.iteritems():
            if len(value)>=maks_length:
                    maks_key = key
                    maks_length = len(value)
    return maks_length, maks_key
```